# Embedded PHP conflicts with OpenSSL: are there solutions?

Tags: php, c++, sockets, ssl

I use complex C++ application that makes a lot of sockets connections with SSL protection via OpenSSL. The application uses both sockets API directly and HTTPS requests via `libcurl`. It works nice for years.

Now I need to add embedded PHP scripts support. So, I linked `libphp5.so` to my application.
And just linking this SO, even when it is unused, causes application to not work as expected. Now any call to `SSL_CTX_new` results in error. The error follows:

```
error:140A90F1:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_new:unable to load ssl2 md5 routines
```

The only explanation I can find is that `libphp5.so` somehow modifies OpenSSL settings during its initialization.

Does anyone know how `libphp5.so` modifies `OpenSSL` and `libcurl` settings?